# How can I edit the tags of a post without correcting any of the wording?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, edits, suggested-edits

I want to edit [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44063760/xmlencoder-writing-to-xml-android-studio-alternative) and replace the "marshmallow" tag with the more Android specific "android-6.0-marshmallow" tag, but I get the warning:

"Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?"

What should I do?

Comment: The simple answer is: Gain 2k rep minimum.

Comment: Mostly true answer: There _is_ something else to improve in this post.  So improve it and you'll be over the 6 character minimum.

Comment: @dizzyf The OP of that post added more info as an answer. I was going to edit that into the question, but I'll leave that honor to you.

Comment: @JasonC Much appreciated. Just submitted my edits.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- The first sentence is missing the word *I* at the beginning. Once that's fixed the N in need should be lower case.
- Does ANDROID STUDIO really need to be capitalised?
- The question sentences could stand to go on separate lines for clarity.
- The title could use some love too as it doesn't read very well grammatically.
- The OP has added additional information as an answer. That should be added into the question instead with an edit message that clearly explains where it's from. The non-answer will get deleted by a moderator fairly soon.

The moral of this story is, if you're going to fix a post, fix all of it. Then you won't need to worry about a 6 character minimum edit length ever again.

Comment: "If you're going to fix a post, fix all of it." <--- Duly noted.